# Convert & to &amp; while preserving existing entity references

Tags: regex, string

I have some dirty data that needs to be scrubbed in a clever way. Basically, I need to entity-code some strings that contain lone `&` into `&amp;`. Unfortunately, some strings also have other character entities in them, so that means I can't do a straightforward global replace.

I've spotchecked some of the 4 million plus strings and what I've seen so far suggests that most of the lone &s are surrounded by whitespace, but I am not a 100% certain.

This is a bit beyond my regex-fu.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Skip the ones which are already valid entities.

Maybe first see which named entities you have in your collection.  I have not tried to create a complete, comprehensive regex.  You want to make sure the regex features all the ones you actually use.  Something like

```
grep -Eio '&[a-z]+;' file more files | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

will show you a frequency list of probable named entities.  Then you can do something like

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/&(?!(?:#(?:\d+|x\x+)|amp|lt|gt|quot|apos|nbsp);)/&amp;/g' file more files
```

This is somewhat ad hoc -- you should extend the list of named entities with all the ones you have in your collection.  Maybe you have a lot of `&rarr;` or `&hellip;` or `&copy;` or `&Aring;` or whatever in there -- you're not showing us samples, so we can't know.  There are certainly [several scores of official named entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) which are missing from this quick and dirty proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead to locate single `&`s.

Per entity name rules, a valid entity name starts with `_` or a letter (in which case only letters, digits, and a single `;` may follow)<sup>*note*</sup>, or it is followed by a `#`, digits, and a terminating `;`. Your example `&1111;` is therefore *not* a valid XML entity, and the `&` should be replaced with `&amp;`.

Use this GREP sequence to locate stray ampersands:

```
&(?![_a-zA-Z]\w*;)(?!#\d+;)
```

and replace with

```
&amp;
```

<sup>*note*</sup> There are a few more characters allowed. See `NameStartChar` and `NameChar` in http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name for a linger list.

Answer (score 0):

```
s/&(?![a-zA-Z#])/&amp;/g
```

will not overmatch.

An ampersand followed by letters could be a named character reference while an ampersand followed by a `#` character could be a numeric character reference.

This will undermatch invalid entity names like `&notanentity;`.

You could tighten it to match `&#` that is not part of a numeric character reference, but I'd grep to see if numeric references even show up in your corpus.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `(\W)&(\W)` to find.. and replace with `$1&amp;$2`

Comment: As I said, not all the lone `&` may be surrounded by spaces. In face, I've found a few that are NOT and cannot be changed due to it being title of a work.

Comment: what are they surrounded with.. and if so why are they called lone?

Comment: I'm using lone to mean that the & is not part of a character entity.

Example: `title = '&mpersand: Adventures in Typ...'`

The & in title is not an entity. Here's another example:

`title = '*@##&@!!: When All Goes to Hell'`

Again, not an entity marker.

Comment: You want to replace & in title if it is a part of word?

Comment: I want to replace & if it is not part of a character entity. If the string contains something like &1111; or &nbsp;, do not replace it with &amp;. Otherwise, do replace it.

Comment: Check the updated answer.. it will cover more than previous.. but not all  :)